# Android:getting illegalstateexception in my new emulator

Tags: android, database, sqlite, exception

In my old emulator the program runs easily without any problem.So i thought the program is fine.But when i try it with new emulator/or other emulators it also runs.The problem starts when i click search button.when i click,program unexpectedly closed.Logcat says illegalstateexception and caused by: no such column as_id.But in my database the _id column exists.I can search in my old emulator without exception.Same code same database.Why it is happening?Why it runs in only one emulator? Any one please kindly tell how to solve the exception.

This is my java class where my program breaks

```
    `
   public class EmployeeList extends ListActivity {

protected EditText searchText;
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
protected Cursor cursor;
protected ListAdapter adapter;
public Integer pid=null;
public DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
public Book book;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST+3;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    searchText = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.searchText);

}

public void search(View view) {                 //when i click here i get exception
    // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "insert successfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE       firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
            new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
   adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this, 
    R.layout.employee_list_item, 
    cursor, 
    new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
    new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
  setListAdapter(adapter);
 registerForContextMenu(getListView());
}
public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, EmployeeDetails.class);
    Cursor cursor = (Cursor) adapter.getItem(position);
    intent.putExtra("EMPLOYEE_ID", cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    startActivity(intent);

  }
  public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {

   menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Delete")
  .setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  switch (item.getItemId()) {
  case DELETE_ID:
  AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info=
  (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();

  delete(info.id);
  return(true);
 }

 return(super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
  }
   private void delete(final long rowId) {
    if (rowId>0) {
     new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle(R.string.delete_title)
    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {

          processDelete(rowId);
        }
       })
       .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel,
                          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                            int whichButton) {
         // ignore, just dismiss
         }
       })
        .show();
    }
  }
   private void processDelete(long rowId) {
     String[] args={String.valueOf(rowId)};

     databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase().delete("employee", "_ID=?", args);
     cursor.requery();
    }

   }      `
```

my database class:

```
    `public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

  public static final String DB_NAME = "employee_directory"; 
    public static final Integer VERSION=1;

    public static final String TABLE_NAME= "employee";
    public static final String _id= "id";
    public static final String firstName= "firstName";
    public static final String lastName= "lastName";
    public static final String title= "title";
    public static final String officePhone= "officePhone";
    public static final String cellPhone= "cellPhone";
    public static final String email= "email";

    public static final String TABLE_SQL = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME+" (" +_id+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " 
    + firstName+ " TEXT, " + lastName+ " TEXT, " + title+ " TEXT, " + officePhone+ " TEXT, " + cellPhone+" TEXT, " + email+" TEXT)";
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("TABLE SQL", TABLE_SQL);
        db.execSQL(TABLE_SQL);

            }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldV, int newV) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS employees");
    onCreate(db);
}

    }`
```

my logcat says:

```
    ` 08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not  execute method of the activity
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at  android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2072)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at  android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at com.example.again.EmployeeList.search(EmployeeList.java:46)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:2067)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  ... 11 more
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id: , while compiling: SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:46)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1345)
    08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  at    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1315)
08-10 01:23:12.655: E/AndroidRuntime(337):  ... 15 more `
```

Comment: When you are creating table the column name is 'id' but when  you are making query it is written as '_id'.

Comment: can you confirm that in your new emulator _id column exist?

Comment: I changed the name from id to _id,but problem was that i did not update the database.I dropped the table,update version.prob solved.Thanks @Shamim Ahmmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be on first Emulator your table is not updated !

and when you run code(which contains bug) on another emulator gives you error

```
you are using _id column in query while column name is  id in table
```

so try by

**either**

changing this  `public static final String _id= "id";`

to

```
 public static final String _id= "_id";
```

inside databse class

**or**

change to

```
 cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE       firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
            new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
```

inside your main class

Comment: Thanks man.After getting your answer i tried all you have told.But still same problem.It stops in search.

Comment: It worked.I dropped the table and then upgrade the version then it was solved.Thanks @Tarsem

Comment: I saw your problem "cannot delete in facebook".I am in the same problem now.I make a button and called the logoutFromFacebook() method.not working.can u help Mr. Tarsem

Comment: @BuppyRahat i think you should ask new question with your relevant code !

Comment: as\you told,see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18226042/androidcannot-logout-from-facebook-and-pass-status